# How to apply a method from my main file in my JUnit test?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Our assignment says we should "write the source code and test code for a function named `sumArray` that accepts an array of ints and returns the sum of all elements from the array".

I think I've got SumArray.java to return `sum` OK, but I'm struggling to apply my method to the test input. Any help please? TIA.

**SumArray.java**

```
 package sumarray;
 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 
 public class SumArray {
 
     private static int n, sum = 0;
 
     public static int sumArray() {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
         n = s.nextInt();
         int a[] = new int[n];
         System.out.println("Enter the elements. (Press [return] after each one)");
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             a[i] = s.nextInt();
             sum = sum + a[i];
         }
         System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
         return sum;
     }
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         sumArray();
     }
 }
```

**SumArrayTest.java**

```
 package sumarray;
 
 import org.junit.Test;
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;
 
 public class SumArrayTest {
 
     public SumArrayTest() {
     }
 
     /**
      * Test of main method, of class SumArray.
      */
     @Test
     public void testMain() {
         System.out.println("main");
         String[] args = null;
         SumArray.main(args);
         int[] intArray = new int[]{2, 3, 4};
         int expectedResult = 9;
 //        int testResult = sumArray({2, 3, 4});
         int testResult = SumArray sumArray(intArray);
         assertEquals(expectedResult, testResult);
 //        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
     }
 }
```

Edit: I've tried to implement what's been suggested so far with some changes; really not sure of any of this is right; a lot of it is guesswork TBH.

```
 package sumarray;
 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 
 public class SumArray {
 
     private static int n, sum = 0;
 
     public static int sumArray;
 
     public static int sumArray(int[] arr) {
         return sum;
     }
 
     public static SumArray input() {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
         n = s.nextInt();
         int a[] = new int[n];
         System.out.println("Enter the elements. (Press [return] after each one)");
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             a[i] = s.nextInt();
             sum = sum + a[i];
         }
         System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
         return new SumArray();
     }
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         SumArray result = input();
         System.out.println(result.sumArray(SumArray));
     }
 }
```

---

```
 package sumarray;
 
 import org.junit.Test;
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;
 
 public class SumArrayTest {
 
     public SumArrayTest() {
     }
 
     @Test
     public void testSumArray() {
         System.out.println("main");
         String[] args = null;
         int[] intArray = new int[]{2, 3, 4};
         int expectedResult = 9;
         assertEquals(expectedResult, SumArray.sumArray(intArray)); 
 //        fail("The test case is a prototype.");
     }
 }
```

The only error I'm seeing currently is 'cannot find symbol' for `SumArray` in `main`.

Comment: it makes no sense at all to test your main method. test the other one instead. but, double check your code: run that method two times after each other, and check the second result.

Comment: @Stultuske - I don't really understand - you say 'run that method two times after each other' - do you mean `sumArray()`? Because I ran it twice and don't see any error. Our assignment says we need to "write the source code and test code for a function named `sumArray` that accepts an array of ints and returns the sum of all elements from the array". Edit - ah, I think I see what you mean by 'it makes no sense at all to test your main method' now. TY.

Comment: @double-hapiness the second time that method runs (if you call it two times from one main method execution) it'll give a wrong result because you don't reset it

Comment: @Stultuske - As far as I can see, you can't call it twice from one main method execution, because the program exits once it has run once.

Comment: you mean to say it is impossible to copy paste a line of code and to re-compile it?

Comment: @Stultuske - clearly that's not what I mean to say, but I can't seem to reproduce the error you are apparently seeing, and I don't know which line of code you are referring to. I tried running it twice, two times, and both times I got the correct result back.

Comment: I was looking at your original code. This version makes even less sense. why have static methods to set those values? that is asking for problems. Do you know what static means?

Comment: @Stultuske - not really. I was trying to implement Mahmoud Yusuf's suggestion to pass the input array to the `sumArray()` method as a parameter instead of reading it from `System.in` within the method body.

Comment: I'll create an answer with more info

Comment: @Stultuske - thanks; that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 package sumarray;
 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 
 public class SumArray {
 
     private static int n, sum = 0;
 
     public static int sumArray() {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
         n = s.nextInt();
         int a[] = new int[n];
         System.out.println("Enter the elements. (Press [return] after each one)");
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             a[i] = s.nextInt();
             sum = sum + a[i];
         }
         System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
         return sum;
     }
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         sumArray();
     }
 }
```

The above is the original code you posted. Now, you say you get the correct output. Yes, here you do:

```
 package sumarray;
 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 
 public class SumArray {
 
     private static int n, sum = 0;
 
     public static int sumArray() {
         Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Enter no. of elements you want in array:");
         n = s.nextInt();
         int a[] = new int[n];
         System.out.println("Enter the elements. (Press [return] after each one)");
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             a[i] = s.nextInt();
             sum = sum + a[i];
         }
         System.out.println("Sum:" + sum);
         return sum;
     }
 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         sumArray(); // this one will return the correct answer
         sumArray(); // this one will not
     }
   }
```

The second one will return wrong data, because you don't reset the value of sum.

You should split the tasks: sumArray should receive an array, and should return the sum of the elements. Either you should change the name of the method, or change the implementation, that is what Mahmoud told you.

```
 package sumarray;
 
 import java.util.Scanner;
 
 public class SumArray {
     private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // create this on class level, not every execution of your method
     
     public static int[] buildArray(int elements) {
        int[] arr = new int[elements];
        for ( int i = 0; i < elements; i++ ) {
            System.out.println("Enter element nr: " + (i+1));
            arr[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
        return arr;
     }
     
     public static int sumArray(int[] input) {
        int sum = 0; // don't use a class level one. especially not a static one, it's value could be altered by another thread
        for ( int in : input ) { // iterate over the array and add the values
          sum += in; // this should be in -> each iteration we add the value of in (the element of the array) to sum
        }
        return sum;         
     }

 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Provide the size of the array: ");
         int param = scan.nextInt();
         int[] array = buildArray(param);
         int result = sumArray(array);
         System.out.println("The sum of the array is: " + result);
     }
   }
```

This approach will land you with far lesser issues. It also doesn't have static variables like n and sum in your class that might lead to wrong results.

Comment: thanks, this is helpful, though it's a bit concerning how far off the mark I seem to have been, TBH. The only problem is, I'm getting "incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int" for `return input;`.

Comment: yes, that's a typo, it should be return sum. I'll correct it

Comment: Thanks, but there still seems to be something wrong, unfortunately. It appears to be returning the length of the array, instead of the sum.

Comment: I notice that it's showing that `in` is not used, which seems incorrect. I tried changing it to `param`, since that's the size of the array (I think), so that would be the required number of iterations through the `for` loop, I assume. But it made no odds, and just showed that `param` was not used instead.

Comment: @double-happiness I wrote that code in a quick moment, was actually working on something entirely different myself :) I'll fix the issue.

Comment: nice one, that works, thanks a lot.The test passes now, too. :)

Answer (score 1):

The main() method is the entry point into the application, you shouldn't test the main() method. Instead, you should test the `sumArray()` method and compare the expected Vs. the actual returned value from the method.

As a side note, you can better pass the input array to the `sumArray()` method as a parameter instead of reading it from `System.in` within the method body.
So your method signature can look like this:

`public static int sumArray(int[] arr)`. The client code which uses this method, which is the main method in your case (or the unit test) can pass the array without bothering the method how this input array was got.

Comment: 'The main() method is the entry point into the application, you shouldn't test the main() method.' Oh, right, I just created the test with Junit, and didn't realise that was wrong. Do I need to rename `testMain()` then? Or can I just get rid of `SumArray.main(args);`? Thanks for the side note; I will see what I can do with that.

Comment: The name of the test method should represent what this method is actually testing. Yes, maybe it's better to do both, rename the test method to something like `testSumArray()` and get rid of the `SumArray.main(args)` part and instead pass the `intArray` variable to your target method.
e.g.: `assertEquals(expectedResult, SumArray.sumArray(intArray))`

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Yusuf. I've attempted to implement your suggestions, admittedly with a good deal of guesswork on my part, but I'm getting an error in `main`. I've added what I've currently got to my OP.